# "Direct" homeomorphism between two subspaces $X$ and $Y$

Tags: general-topology, functions

I'm trying to find a homeomorphism between spaces X and Y, where

$$ X = \{(x,y)|x^2>y>2x^2-1\} $$
$$ Y = \{(x,y)| |x|<1 \wedge |y|<1\} .$$

I checked that X and Y are homeomorphic with "extra steps", meaning I found $A$ and $B$ so that $X \approx A \approx B \approx Y$ ($A$ is a semicircle and $B$ a rectangle). I'm now wondering if it could be done in one step, but I couldn't find such a function between $X$ and $Y$. My idea was to stretch every vertical line in $X$ to a vertical line in $Y$ (as on the pictures), but such a function is then not defined for $x = 0$. The one I thought about is

$$ (x,y) \mapsto (x, \frac{x^2-1}{2x^2}(y-(2x^2-1))+x^2)$$

but it might as well be a terrible candidate for a homeomorphism. Thank you for any help!:)

Thank you for any help and sorry for my poor writing. :)

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: "My idea was to stretch every vertical line in $X$ to a vertical line in $Y$(as on the pictures), but such a function is then not defined for $x=0$." I don't see the issue - if done properly, this seems to work.